# How to use drools without eclipse JDT library

Tags: java, drools, eclipse-jdt

recently I am using Drools in eclipse. When I was running program, there is one exception:

> org.drools.RuntimeDroolsException: Unable to load dialect 'org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration:java:org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration'
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.addDialect(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:310)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.buildDialectConfigurationMap(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:295)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.init(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:184)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration.(PackageBuilderConfiguration.java:162)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.(PackageBuilder.java:277)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.(PackageBuilder.java:205)
>       at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:34)
>       at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:46)
>       at com.adsc.cybersage.rules.DroolEngineInit.readKnowledgeBase(DroolEngineInit.java:48)
>       at com.adsc.cybersage.rules.DroolEngineInit.initializeDrools(DroolEngineInit.java:32)

I search online and found that this is because I didn't add eclipse JDT library org.eclipse.jdt.core.jar, then I add this jar and the program works well. But I don't want to add eclipse JDT Library because its license is strict. So is there any alternative jar which is under a not strict license I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I am compiling and running Drools without org.eclipse.jdt.core.jar, calling javac and java from the command line (actually, a shell script).

```
PROTOBUF=protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar 
root=/extra/drools-distribution-5.5.0.Final/binaries
tag=5.5.0.Final
export CLASSPATH=".:$root/drools-core-${tag}.jar:$root/knowledge-api-${tag}.jar:$root/knowledge-internal-api-${tag}.jar:$root/drools-compiler-${tag}.jar:$root/antlr-2.7.7.jar:$root/antlr-3.3.jar:$root/antlr-runtime-3.3.jar:$root/ecj-3.5.1.jar:$root/mvel2-2.1.3.Final.jar:/extra/quartz-1.8.3/quartz-1.8.3.jar:$root/drools-decisiontables-${tag}.jar:$root/drools-templates-${tag}.jar:$root/xstream-1.4.1.jar:$root/jxl-2.6.10.jar:$root/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar:$root/$PROTOBUF"
```

Then javac and java are called.

Of course, when you are running within Eclipse, you may indeed need Eclipse stuff. You can develop and test under Eclipse and then compile DRL and execute your application using the aforementioned technique.